# Rails choking on the content of this request because of protect_from_forgery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to simply test my RESTful API with cURL. Using the following invocation:

```
curl -d "name=jimmy" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://127.0.0.1:3000/people.xml -i
```

Rails is dying though:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  :8:in `synchronize'

Looks like it's running this through a protect_from_forgery filter. I thought protect_from_forgery is excluded for non-HTML HTTP POST/PUT/DELETE type requests? This is clearly targeting the XML format.

If I pass actual XML content, it works. But my users will be submitting POST data as URL encoded parameters. I know all the various ways I can disable protect_from_forgery but what's the proper way of handling this? I want to leave it on so that when I do have HTML based forms and handle format.html, I don't forget to re-enable it for then. I want users to be able to make HTTP POST requests to my XML-based API though and not get bombarded with this.

Comment: Why can't your users post xml-data? Or why can't you give them an authenticity_token for their request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about going this way?

In your controller:

```
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :api

      def api
        @callback = request.body.read
        if !@callback.blank?
          People.create :name => @callback
       end
      end
```

---

In routes.rb:

```
  map.api '/api', :controller => "people", :action => "api"
```

---

Then curl:

```
curl -d "jimmy" http://localhost:3000/api -i
```

This is what i get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 21 Apr 2010 16:31:52 GMT
ETag: "1bafa7f069ba62f46577e0172a29b7cc"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Runtime: 141
Content-Length: 476
Set-Cookie: _tsearchtest_session=BAh7BjoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNjJlOTViOGZhODc1NmU5NDg1MWUyYWQ3YWQ0NzFiYjU%3D--651c3bfcbb0f180c72653379678d410711ead2eb; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>People: api</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/scaffold.css?1271863770" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<p style="color: green"></p>
```

---

Comment: I guess if you don't want to give the authenticity token then just bypass for only the action containing your api endpoint using `  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :your_action_here`

Comment: and I guess there are other ways to secure the curl request (like API keys and the like).

Comment: @graza, you are right. But will it not be effective only if @randombits is using an authentication system for his app? If not, is there any way other than either giving away the auth token or bypassing it for the particular action?

Comment: I recently built an intranet web-app with REST API where I work.  The only servers using the REST API would have fixed IP addresses.  I didn't want to turn off "protect from forgery" completely, so the options I could see were SSL, or just check the source IP.  I opted for the latter (for simplicity).